# jQuery closing a modal when a try to click anywhere

Tags: jquery, django, toggle, tailwind-css, simplemodal

jQuery is showing unpredictable behavior, the following code displays a custom modal with a form inside but if I try to click anywhere, including the form inputs it calls the jQuery function and closes it. What may I be doing wrong?

```
let fecharModal = $('#fecharModal');
let conteudoModal = $('#conteudoModal');
let modal = $('#modal');
let fora = $('#fora');

$(modal).on('click', [fecharModal, fora], function () {
        $(modal).hide();
        $(conteudoModal).html("");
        return false;
    });

        <div id="modal" class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto hidden">
            <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
                <div id="fora" class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
                <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full">
                    <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
                        <div class="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                            <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left" id="conteudoModal">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: probably should move that `$(modal).hide();` functionality to a backdrop click event, now it looks like its in a modal click event

Comment: the problem is that you are telling jquery to hide the model when clicking in the model ``$(modal).hide();``

Comment: Tried switching the variables, using the full on function, moving the function elsewhere and the results are either not working or doing the exact same thing reported in the problem.